# How can I write arc text in postscript file

Tags: text, postscript

I have this, But I want to have text alignment like an arc. Is it possible?

```
   /outputtext {
       /data exch def
       /rot exch def
       /xfont exch def
      /y1 exch def
     /x1 exch def
    /Times-Roman findfont
    xfont scalefont
    setfont
    x1 y1 moveto
    rot rotate
    data show

    rot neg rotate
 } def



% x y fontsize rotation (text) outputtext
20 300 12 0 (text1) outputtext
20 400 12 90 (text2) outputtext
20 500 12 90 (text3) outputtext
20 600 12 0 (text4) outputtext
showpage
```

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what the result of this code should be? A detailed description, or a hand-drawn sketch?

Answer (score 4):

Adobe's famous [**Blue Book**](http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/BLUEBOOK.PDF) (*PostScript Language Tutorial and Cookbook, Adobe Systems, Addison-Wesley 1985; ISBN 0201101793*) contains a very well explained example how to do this.

See pages 168ff and the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have followed that Book...But I want this curve dynamically. NO translate, Like my font can be increase or decrease. No of charter can also be vary. So do you have any nice and easy way to do this.

Comment: @user1600540: Your original question didn't state anything about 'dynamically'. Nor did it mention which resources you used. Nor do I understand from your last comment what you mean by 'dynamically'. Please consider to edit your question and make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you want to avoid `translate`, and it's not clear what you mean by "dynamically". But this code gives *rotation-like* effects without translating. But you can't really hug an arc without defining a center (either with `translate` and `rotate`, or algebraically with `cos` and `sin`) and accounting (somehow) for the character widths. The Adobe example code does all of this. My code here does not.

[image: Some wildly rotated text]

```
%!

/rottxt { 4 dict begin
    /ang exch def
    /str exch def
    /ang ang str length div def
    { pop pop ang rotate }
    str
    kshow
end } def

30 150 moveto
/Palatino-Roman 20 selectfont
(This   is) -20 rottxt
( some  ro) 20 rottxt
(tated   T) -40 rottxt
(ext!!!!!) -100 rottxt
showpage
```

Answer (score 0):

I think at long last I understand what you're trying to do. The part about `translate` really threw me for a loop. There's nothing to fear about `translate`. And it **will** be necessary. Translate is what lets you control where the center of rotation is.

So you want to draw text on a circle, but you want to change font parameters dynamically. Font-changes in the middle of an arc. That'll take some thought. I'll edit when I've got more.