# LaTeX curved timeline

Tags: latex, timeline

I am writing a report in latex. In one of the paragraphs I thought it would good to portrait the history in a curved timeline. I found some packages for different timelines - horizontal, vertical, multi-lines, etc., however I want to create a curved (snake shaped) line and put text around it. Is that possible?

Apologies if there is a relative thread opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several programs and packages that could do that. Here are some that come to mind.

Drawing "languages":

- [PostScript](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/) (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599627/how-can-i-write-arc-text-in-postscript-file))
- [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/)
- [pstricks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PSTricks)
- [metapost](http://tex.loria.fr/prod-graph/zoonekynd/metapost/metapost.html)
- [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/all/) (see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/tikz-bend-text-so-that-it-follows-a-line))

Drawing programs:

- [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/)

If you just want to slap together a single picture, I would guess that inkscape might be the easiest way.

The downside of all the "drawing languages" is that they have a significant learning curve. The upside is that all are very powerful. IIRC all support things like (aligned) text along a curve.

In TeX circles, TikZ seems to be most popular at this moment. It is included in TeXLive, so chances are you already have it. In my opinion, TikZ is generally more "high level" than PostScript, pstricks and metapost.

Comment: After going through all your suggestions, I decided that TikZ would be most suitable for what I needed. I spent sometime researching the package and in the end successfully achieved what I initially wanted. Thank you.